# How Can I update each password in my database with hashed bcrypt version?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

So as you can see. I am trying to take the previous password in the column and update it with the hashed version. For some reason the save on the document isn't firing right away. So I tried using async await and even creating a custom async await foreach to await the callback and the save. However, Mongoose seems to be waiting for all of the saves to come in before applying the save.

This is the error that I get.

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 505)
>   (node:2440)

````
const User = require("./models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;


async function hashIt(user) {
    console.log(user);
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.Password, salt, async (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            user.Password = hash;
            const id = await user.save();
            console.log(id);
        })
    });
}

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        await callback(array[index], index, array);
    }
}

async function mySeed() {
    try {
        User.find({}, async (err, users) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            asyncForEach(users, async (user) => {
                await hashIt(user);
            })
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

async function fullThing(){
    mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(async () => {
        await mySeed();
        console.log("finished successfully");
    })
}

fullThing();```
````

Comment: I have tested my solution, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the response. The solution turned out to be that w=majority for some reason needed to be removed from the db connection. After removing that. Everything began working fine. Wrapping the connect with the catch did help to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar routine running on my current back front end system, and below is how I have adapted your code to mine; mine is working, therefore I hope yours will work as well. I believe the problem is that is you are not catching potential errors, that happened to me a lot in the beginning, and sometimes it still happens when I am tired.

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  bcrypt.hash(user.Password, salt, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    user.Password = hash;
    const id = user
      .save()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("okay");
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

  });
});
```

In case it does not work, please, let me know what comes out as error.

**Appendix**

I have tested my solution below:

```
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
require("./connection");

//creating user schema
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

UserSchema = new Schema({ name: String, password: String });
var User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

const user = new User({ name: "Jorge Pires", password: "Corona Virus" });

console.log(` Before hashing ${user.password}`);

//---------------------------------------------------------------
//Uncomment here to save the user before hashing, it will change anyway, therefore no need!
// user.save();
// User.create({ name: "Jorge Pires", password: "Corona Virus" });
//--------------------------------------------------------------
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
  //generates the salta
  if (err) console.log(err);
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
    //creates the hash
    if (err) throw err;
    user.password = hash; //saves the hash
    const id = user
      .save()
      .then(() => {
        console.log(` after hashing ${user.password}`);
        console.log(` Here goes the user id  ${user.id}`);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });
});
```

Output sample:

```
Before hashing Corona Virus
we are connected mongoose-tutorial
 after hashing $2a$10$84MqPsiiMGA/KTHKFbytVOD5/su6rXiE7baA2TmsLzPMe.Y45aL9i
 Here goes the user id  5e710a0bd4385c05b0cd827f
```